# Remove left padding from Bootstrap navbar and maintain correct responsive behaviour

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

**I would like to remove the left padding from the navbar below:**

[image]

**and top padding in a narrow viewport:**

[image]

**Navbar code & JSFiddle:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Discuss</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wx6bx3pr/

**Already attempted solution - setting the padding of .container-fluid to zero gets the desired outcome in the wide viewport:**

[image]

```
.container-fluid
{
  padding: 0;
}
```

**Except completely breaks it in a narrow viewport, with the active menu item protruding beyond the navbar, and no spacing between the container and the text of menu items:**

[image]

**How do I get the desired solution without breaking the narrow viewport?**

**Many thanks.**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try a negative margin on the navbar like this..

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-nav {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: -15px;
  }
}

.navbar-nav {
    margin: 0 -15px;
}
```

http://codeply.com/go/leAaYlOaYd